# Admit (to) cheating?

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions

I'm trying to figure out which one is the right way, grammatically:

- Why won't you admit cheating in the exam?
- Why won't you admit to cheating in the exam?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All following usages are correct:

[Admit](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/admit):

> I am willing to admit that I do make mistakes. [VERB that]
>
> Up to two-thirds of drivers admit to driving while feeling tired. [VERB + to]
>
> I'd be ashamed to admit feeling jealous. [VERB verb-ing]

(Collins Dictionary)